# How re-render page in next.js / typescript after clicked useState?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have problem with re-render body of page.
When I second time clicked Next Product, I want see again Loading..., nad next new product. Bellow my code, what is wrong with it? What I should fix?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";

export const getProducts = (id: number) => {
  return async () => {
    const rest = await fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${id}`);
    const data: ProductApi = await rest.json();
    return data;
  };
};

export const ProductsPage = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const { isLoading, data, error } = useQuery("products", getProducts(page));

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (!data || error) {
    return <div>Error#!</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>{data.title}</div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>Next Product</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductsPage;
...
```

Comment: What happens when you click now?

Comment: I would start by doing `setPage(page => page + 1)`

Comment: @Tushar - data will replace, but I don't see again Loading... information.

Comment: If you do not see `loading` and data is changing maybe that is how useQuery works. Your API might be fast to respond

Comment: @TusharShahi I want remove old render and re-render.
Beacouse when I render first element, and click next I see
FirstElement
SecondElement

I want see
Loading...
and next only -> Second Element